# Programmatically adding a signature to an email

Tags: email, mime

I have a requirement to add a signature to emails passing through a specialised proxy server. There doesn't seem to be a very good way to do this, and my initial thoughts are to:

1. If the mail is non-MIME, or is `text/plain`, just add text to the bottom of the body,
   with a preceding "-- " line (an old convention for adding signatures
   to `text/plain` messages; see [RFC3676, 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3676#section-4.3))
2. If the mail is `multipart/mixed`, find the last boundary, and insert
   a new `multipart/alternative' entity above it, containing plain and
   HTML versions of the sig. This has the disadvantage that the sig may
   appear below attachments, though.
3. If the mail is not `multipart/mixed`, make it `multipart-mixed`, and
   demote the existing entities into the mixed section; now add the
   `multipart/alternative` signature as the last part of the new
   `multipart/mixed`. Same disadvantage as (2).

Seems pretty long-winded. Any ideas on better ways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I would add some hyperlinks to your references to make it easier for people to quickly view what you're referencing, such as "RFC3676, 4.3". Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: Done - dozens of references for MIME, though - too complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded this as above, and it's fine on Yahoo, gmail, AOL, GMX, and Thunderbird, with the MIME validated [here](http://tools.ietf.org/tools/msglint/) and [here](http://www.mimevalidator.net/index.html).
The problem was that I forgot, again, about Microsoft's complete inability to read an RFC. If a `multipart/mixed` section contains two `multipart/alternative` sections, where each one contains a `text/plain` and a `text/html` alternative, then Outlook/hotmail actually displays *both* alternatives in the second `multipart/alternative`. So, it displays both the plain signature, and the HTML version.

The fix is straightforward - instead of adding a second `multipart/alternative` for the signatures, I instead add a single `text/html` section, containing only the HTML signature. This displays correctly on all the MUAs above, including the brain-dead ones. Not exactly ideal, but I could enable the fix only for Microsoft recipients, and let them sort things out if they have persuaded their MUA to display only plain text.

Answer (score 0):

if only interesting in `text/html` and not in `text/plain` part, a bit simpler implementation will be to trasform the `text/html` into `multipart/mixed` with your html signature.

**before**

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  text/html
```

**after**

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  multipart/mixed
    text/html
    text/html <== your signature
```